# Unity3D clothes swap system

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am designing a clothes system that character can change clothes.

Right now I have two methods coming in my mind, the first is the easiest one: just deactive old clothes and activate new clothes game object, but this of course will take up a lot of memory.

The second way is to load mesh data from new clothes skinmeshrenderder to old clothes skinmeshrenderer. But this will cause extra CPU calculation during gameplay.

I wonder which one is good or is there other methods normally used in the game?

Comment: And what about just adding new clothes to a scene from prefab, make it as a child of your model and destroyed old ones?

Comment: That's a good idea too! I am more concerned about how first class standard game achieves this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AAA products use more sophisticated ways to load models and it dependent on how dynamically model need to change. For ex. if you chose clothes at beginning of the game and can chose from dozens of clothes game will load only one model and remove rest of them (or not load at all). But if clothes changes dynamically like when hero uses different attack or tools (ex. Bayonetta when kicking have black clothes but when use special hair attack is naked) all models are loaded and just swap when needed. And finally both techniques can be used simultaneously. But if you creating production when memory or speed is not in concern you can choose anything you like.

Comment: So if I only choose clothes only at the beginning, can I actually append all my clothes to my character gameObject, and destroy them when loading into next scene? I tried Resource.Load(), but the clothes loaded became invisible, any chance you know why? My clothes required a root bone.

Comment: @ywj7931 It's dependent on what resource type you loaded but if it's model prefab you need to instantiate it. Look at second example on [documentation page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).

Comment: Yes I used that example, GameObject newobject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Shirt_02", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject; the prefab is the t-shirt gameobject consisting of skinmeshrenderer. But the mesh is not visible in the game even I manually set the root bone correctly in the inspector

Comment: You probably don't need to load resources like this you just need to instantiate prefab that you link in editor. But if you want use this anyway if nothing changed between versions your prefab need to be inside folder named "Resources".

Comment: Gotcha, thank you!